# Different output from same code parsing simiiar tab-delimited files

Tags: perl, shell

The Perl script below is written in a shell.

If I use the tab-delimited file `numeric` then I get the desired result of each line parsed accordingly. However, if I use the file `alpha` as input then only the first line is parsed.

The only difference between `alpha` and `numeric` is that `numeric` has `NC_000023`

```
NC_000023.11:g.41747805_41747806delinsTT
NC_000023.11:g.41750615C>A
```

while `alpha` has `NC_0000X`

```
NC_0000X.11:g.41747805_41747806delinsTT
NC_0000X.11:g.41750615C>A
```

What am I missing?

#### numeric

```
Input Variant   Errors  Chromosomal Variant Coding Variant(s)
NM_003924.3:c.*18_*19delGCinsAA     NC_000023.11:g.41747805_41747806delinsTT    LRG_513t1:c.*18_*19delinsAA NM
NM_003924.3:c.013G>T        NC_000023.11:g.41750615C>A  LRG_513t1:c.13G>T
```

#### alpha

```
Input Variant   Errors  Chromosomal Variant Coding Variant(s)
NM_003924.3:c.*18_*19delGCinsAA     NC_0000X.11:g.41747805_41747806delinsTT LRG_513t1:c.*18_*19delinsAA NM_003924.3:c.*18_*19delinsAA
NM_003924.3:c.013G>T        NC_0000X.11:g.41750615C>A   LRG_513t1:c.13G>T   NM_003924.3:c.13G>T
```

#### Perl

```
perl -ne '

next if $. == 1;

if ( /.*del([A-Z]+)ins([A-Z]+).*NC_0+([^.]+)\..*g\.([0-9]+)_([0-9]+)/ ) { # indel
    print join( "\t", $3, $4, $5, $1, $2 ), "\n";
}
else {

    while ( /\t*NC_(\d+)\.\S+g\.(\d+)(\S+)/g ) {

        # conditional parse

        ( $num1, $num2, $common ) = ( $1, $2, $3 );
        $num3 = $num2;

        if ( $common =~ /^([A-Z])>([A-Z])$/ ) {      # SNP
            ( $ch1, $ch2 ) = ( $1, $2 );
        }
        elsif ( $common =~ /^del([A-Z])$/ ) {        # deletion
            ( $ch1, $ch2 ) = ( $1, "-" );
        }
        elsif ( $common =~ /^ins([A-Z])$/ ) {        # insertion
            ( $ch1, $ch2 ) = ( "-", $1 );
        }
        elsif ( $common =~ /^_(\d+)del([A-Z]+)$/ ) { # multi deletion
            ( $num3, $ch1, $ch2 ) = ( $1, $2, "-" );
        }
        elsif ( $common =~ /^_(\d+)ins([A-Z]+)$/ ) { # multi insertion
            ( $num3, $ch1, $ch2 ) = ( "-", $1, $2 );
        }

        printf( "%d\t%d\t%d\t%s\t%s\n", $num1, $num2, $num3, $ch1, $ch2 ); # output

        map { undef } ( $num1, $num2, $num3, $common, $ch1, $ch2 );
    }
}' numeric
```

#### output

```
23  41747805    41747806    GC  AA
23  41750615    41750615    C   A
```

**output using alpha:**

```
X   41747805    41747806    GC  AA
```

If I use `\w` instead of `\d` in the `while` condition, like this

```
while ( /\t*NC_(\w+)\.\S+g\.(\d+)(\S+)/g ) { ... }
```

I get this result

```
X   41747805    41747806    GC  AA
0   41750615    41750615    C   A
```

Why the zero in `$1`

Comment: You mention tab delimited in the header, but there are no tabs in your files. And you are not doing anything with tabs. Beside the `while (/\t*`, which is useless at that point, because it doesn't matter if a `\t` is in the input or not.

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to learn `perl` which is very tricky so I make a lot of mistakes, but am learning.

Comment: Your code is very badly laid out and difficult to read. It's fine with me if you want to do that to yourself, but if you're asking for free help from the rest of the world then it would be more appropriate to make an  effort and show something legible. You must also *always* `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` at the top of every program you write. They will help to reveal any trivial errors before you look to others to fix your code.

Comment: @ULick: Please write up your first comment as an answer.

Comment: @Borodin I added the `use strict` and `use warnings` to my script.... in terms of indenting the code what would you suggest or advise. Is there a general guideline to follow?  Thank you :).

Comment: @Borodin, yep, moved it.

Comment: Take a look at [`perstyle`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) and [`perltidy`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perltidy). And it's best not to use twenty-line "one-liners"; put your code in a file.

Comment: Your first regex picks up lines which have `del.*ins` (I simplify it) in it. I think it likely, that you don't find one of the four regex in the else part. Depends on your real input. At least for the input examples that part is useless.

Comment: I'm intrigued to know what you intended by `map { undef } ( $num1, $num2, $num3, $common, $ch1, $ch2 )`? What it actually does is generate a list of six `undef` values and then discards it, although that's probably optimised out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `while (/\t*NC_(\d+)\.` will not match 'NC_0000X.11', due to the 'X' and the regex is looking for digits only.

After the change you made, `NC_(\w+)` will match 'NC_0000X' and `$num1` is set to '0000X'.

Your `printf "%d...." $num1 ...` will print a 0 for non numeric input. As `$num1` is '0000X', it will print as 0.

The input example suggests, that each line consists of fields, which are separated by white-space. Some fields are of interest, otheres not. Each field holds recognizable information.

Your program should follow this structure.

- Read the file line by line
- split the line into fields
- skip fields, which are not of interest, e.g. non NC.*
- extract the necessary information from the field
- do whatever necessary, sum it up, collect it
- print the information at the level needed. Per field, line, file or after all files

It is much easier to work on smaller chuncks instead of finding a regex which works for the whole line. It is much easier to read, understand and maintain.